# Создать package.json из существующей папки node_modules

Tags: node.js, angularjs

У меня в проекте есть папка `node_modules`, при наличии которой возможна работа с Angular CLI. Однако файл `package.json` не полностью описывает нужные зависимости, и нет возможности на основе него развернуть требуемое окружение.

Подскажите, как мне сгенерировать файл `package.json` на основе папки с модулями?

Версия Node.js - 10.16

Comment: Запусти проект `npm start`, естественно он не запуститься и будет требовать зависимости... И установи их в ручную...  Если конечно у тебя нет списка всех модулей.... А если есть, то просто установи вручную...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const pathToDir= './node_modules';
const targetFile = 'package.json';
const dir = fs.readdirSync(pathToDir);
const result = {};
dir.forEach(dirName => {
  const d = path.resolve(pathToDir, dirName, targetFile);
  if (fs.existsSync(d)){
    const file = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(d, 'utf-8'));
    result[file.name] = file.version;
  }
});
console.log(result)
```

Правда полученные данные будут избыточными, т.к. здесь будут включены зависимости тех модулей, которые использует проект

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я знаю, для npm такое не возможно. Поэтому требуемые зависимости придётся добавлять в `package.json` самостоятельно.

Answer (score 0):

Есть вариант удалить node_modules и начать запускать проект через node, тогда по очереди будет выбивать зависимости ошибками и ты сможешь их установить вручную через npm.

Comment: Можно попробовать, но боюсь ошибиться и начать плавать в разных несовместимых между собой версий пакетов.